# Sequential variables assignement format in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Currently using "Auto Format" in PhpStorm uses spaces to align variables like

```
$objUser = new User();
$arrUserSongs = $objUser->Songs()
```

to

```
$objUser      = new User();
$arrUserSongs = $objUser->Songs()
```

Can it be made to use "tabs" instead of spaces as using DIFF with repositories makes the code clear [using dots (spaces are converted to dots) makes it look ugly]

Comment: I don't know about PhpStorm, but tabs width can usually be changed in IDE settings. Which means that if you try to align assignments with tabs, it will work for you but maybe not for other people. So what you want is a bad idea anyway and probably why PhpStorm doesn't allow it.

Comment: No -- it uses space for consistency as TAB can be configured to be 4 spaces on one system and 8 on another. Plus, with tabs it's difficult to align properly (possible extra empty space on longest assignment) Visually it also looks weird to have mix of TAB and SPACE in the *middle* of the assignment.

Comment: @LazyOne I normally use Tab as a separator for alignment of code. Is it possible to change the default behavior to use tab instead of space? Note: for other alignments, we can use TAB's, but only for variable alignment it forcefully uses spaces

Comment: AFAIK -- no (but there is a chance that I am wrong). You can always ask such question on PhpStorm forum http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/wi?view=discussions where corresponding dev may answer it or file Feature Request to the Issue Tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 3):

After a few searches, I figured out how to adjust this; you can do it by going to:

**1. File menu.

 1. Settings.

 2. Editor tab.

 3. Code Style

 4. PHP**

Now select the scheme you want to edit, then:
Go to **Wrapping and Braces**
Scroll down to **Assignment statement** and check **Align consecutive assignments**

You can find more details about the new changes here:
[New and Changed Formatting Options in PhpStorm 8](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/06/new-and-changed-formatting-options-in-phpstorm-8/)

And here's a duplicate of your question:
[PHPStorm 9 align assignments in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787223/phpstorm-9-align-assignments-in-php)