# PHPStorm 9 align assignments in PHP

Tags: phpstorm

After many searches, it seems I don't have the option to align consecutive assignments of variables in PHP. I can align key/value pairs in arrays, but that's it.

It also seems older PHPStorm versions have it.

Is that possible in PHPStorm 9 ? If so, how ? If not, is it really much better than older versions ? I just started using it (coming from Sublime).

This is an example of non formatted code :

```
$sExample = 'Example !';
$sAnotherOneHere = 'Again ?';
$sAndTheLast = 'ENOUGH !';
```

And that's the format result :

```
$sExample        = 'Example !';
$sAnotherOneHere = 'Again ?';
$sAndTheLast     = 'ENOUGH !';
```

Comment: Can you post a formatted example?

Comment: I updated my original post to fit an example in.

Comment: If you also want to align array's key-value pairs check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795404/269622

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The option is still there and it works flawlessly.

Search for it under Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Assignment Statement. It's called "Align consecutive assignments".

Comment: You might want to enable `Class field/constant groups -> Align constants` as well

Comment: what about with `$sExample => 'Example !';`

Comment: `Array initializer -> Align key-value pairs`